# A bit of a keyboard problem

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard, bios

So I've looked all over but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere nor can I find a problem exactly like mine so maybe someone can help me.

I want to be very specific just in case I did something wrong so bear with me. I have a Toshiba Satellite Laptop that's about 2 years old now and am relatively new to Linux, so naturally I started with Ubuntu and my keyboard worked fine.

However I started looking into other Distros because there are so many to decide on. I installed Zorin OS 9 by usb and proceeded to check out it's features but while I was playing one of its pre-installed games my **internal** keyboard seemed to stop working. After numerous failures to get my keyboard running again by rebooting I installed (and am currently running) Kubuntu with a complete wipe of my drive. Still my keyboard is not responding **sometimes**.

I say sometimes because sometimes after rebooting maybe 8-9 times my computer decides to recognize my internal keyboard which is very odd to me. Currently it is working fine but when I reboot it won't work again. The same keyboard problem occurs in Recovery mode. It's also worth noting that when I enter my BIOS password my keyboard functions just fine, Its not until the OS starts loading when my Caps Lock and Num Lock turn off and my keyboard is rendered useless. Usb keyboards work fine.

Solutions I've tried so far are that don't seem to work:

1. Changing text at `/etc/default/grub` from

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   to

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp=1 i8042.dumbkbd=1"
   ```

   and rebooting
2. Changing My input method to various things including removing an input method and rebooting
3. Adding another language and rebooting

If you need any info that I haven't stated here let me know and I will do my best to tell you. And If I am a duplicate post could you please link me to a solution! Thank you!